# Toggle Element on HTTP response

Tags: http, angular

I'm pretty new with Angular 2. I'm working on angular2 + node js setup. In project its a simple authentication call. What I want is to show a div block if login api returns an error.

Here is what I have done.

LoginComponent

```
private loginResponse: any;
private submitted: boolean;
private error: boolean = false;
private errorMessage: string;
public loginForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    // if user is authenticated, redirect him/her to dashboard
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
    }
    this.submitted = false;
}

// authenticate user
getLogin() {
    // return if form is invalid
    if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
        return false;
    }
    this.submitted = true;
    var formData = this.loginForm.value;
    this.auth.login(formData.email, formData.password, this.translate.currentLang)
        .subscribe(
            (data: Response) => {
                this.loginResponse = data;
                if (this.loginResponse.result) {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', this.loginResponse.data);
                    window.location.reload();
                } 
                this.submitted = false;
                this.error = true;
                this.errorMessage = this.loginResponse.message;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
}
```

LoginComponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" id="sign_in" (ngSubmit)="getLogin()" autocomplete="false">
            <div *ngIf="error" class="text-danger text-justify msg">
                {{ errorMessage }}
            </div>
```

Issue is, when server returns result false, I'm setting error property to true but it does not show any effect.

Comment: Suggest add tag "angular2"

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to `private error: boolean = false;`:

As per the [docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html):

> When a member is marked private, it cannot be accessed from outside of
>   its containing class

and since templates do not exist within component classes, but outside of them this could be the reason you have this issue.

You could try changing your code to something like this:

```
private loginResponse: any;
private submitted: boolean;
private errorMessage: string;
public loginForm: FormGroup;

error: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
    // if user is authenticated, redirect him/her to dashboard
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
    }
    this.submitted = false;
}

// authenticate user
getLogin() {
    // return if form is invalid
    if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
        return false;
    }
    this.submitted = true;
    var formData = this.loginForm.value;
    this.auth.login(formData.email, formData.password, this.translate.currentLang)
        .subscribe(
            (data: Response) => {
                this.loginResponse = data;
                if (this.loginResponse.result) {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', this.loginResponse.data);
                    window.location.reload();
                    this.error = false;
                } 
                this.submitted = false;
                this.error = true;
                this.errorMessage = this.loginResponse.message;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
}
```

changed to `error: boolean;` and added `this.error = false` if response is ok.

Comment: Unfortunately not working ..  strange behavior is, the change is not reflecting instantly. On clicking signin button error message does not show. But when I click on signin again message shows even before response is received. Could it be something event related? like angular2 template needs to know that value of "error" is changed

Comment: It might be an issue elsewhere in the code, perhaps you could set up a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) to reproduce this. Would definitely help in debugging

Comment: I found the issue. It was because of another module for translation, which had custom "changeDetactionStrategy" and there was no listener for it. I removed it and now its working like a charm.. !! :)   Thanks for your suggestion, learnt about private, public :)